# UFT click an element based on a given property value

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

I'm working with a date selector, and I'm trying for my UFT script to pick an appointment date 3 days from today's date. I have set up that value specifically to match the property value format in the HTML code:

14

My question is: How can I instruct UFT to look for a property value by matching whatever is in the "aria-label" property with the value that I have defined in my data table?

Also, I noticed that the 'Tab index' is -1, not sure if that has anything to do
Much appreciated

I have the following code, but UFT does not recognize it "strAppointmentDate" is the cell in the data table where I defined the desired date:

iDate= strAppointmentDate
Set dd = Browser("Browser").Page("Select Appointment").WebButton("aria-label:=" &iDate, "html tag:=td", "index:=-1")

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"aria-label"` try `"attribute/aria-label"`.